# How to distinguish birth and death bifurcations?

Tags: real-analysis, morse-theory, critical-point-theory, bifurcation

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ have a **degenerate** critical point at $x = 0 \, ($*ie*, $f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = 0)$.

Perturbing $f$ locally around $0$ may cause multiple scenarios:

- **Birth:** the critical point splits into multiple (non-degenerate) critical points. Example: $f(x) = x^3$ with perturbation $f(x) - \varepsilon x$ (for $\varepsilon > 0$).
- **Death:** the critical point completely disappears. Example: $f(x) = x^3$ with perturbation $f(x) + \varepsilon x$.
- **Neither**. The critical point is just slightly perturbed, and then no-longer degenerate, but it neither splits nor dies. An example can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4881715/656302).

---

**Overarching question:** Consider the three scenarios of perturbation I described above (birth/death of critical points, or neither). Given a function $f$ and a degenerate critical point $x$ of $f$, is there a way to distinguish which scenarios could happen, and which could not?

I would be perfectly happy with references treating this topic; as most results concerning birth-death bifurcation (that I could find) take a lot of statements for granted, as most of this is now part of the "mathematical folklore". (This is the reason I'm asking this on MO, and not MSE; for this is for research purposes; and the original question I asked on MSE on a similar topic took a long time to gain an answer).

---

*Incomplete attempt at answering this question:* the Hopf index.

*Edit: as was pointed out in the comments, a post is technically only allowed to contain one question; so whichever comes next is NOT a question. It is my attempt at the problem.*

As explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4882275/656302): to each (isolated) critical point $x$ of $f$, one can associate a Hopf index, $\lambda(x)$. The sum of all these indices (over all critical points of $f$) is a topological invariant by the Poincaré-Hopf theorem; and hence, in particular:

If $x$ can be killed by some small perturbation of $f$, then $\lambda(x) = 0$.

Hence, my first question is:

**1a)** is the converse true? *ie*, if $\lambda(x) = 0$, there exists a perturbation of $f$ that kills $x$?

If this is true, then this would give us a criterion that identifies when a critical point can die (it would be necessary and sufficient that $\lambda(x) = 0$). If not:

**1b)** Is there a criterion that allows us to determine whether the critical point $x$ can die or not? (when submitted to an arbitrary perturbation of $f$)

Either way, the question I am mostly interested in is the following:

**2)** In either case: are death bifurcations **rare**? In other words: given a generic $f$ with a degenerate critical point; is it true that this critical point cannot die? (If **1a)** holds, then this reduces to asking that for a generic $f$ and $x$ (degenerate), then $\lambda(x) \ne 0$).

The reason I care about this question is that, in my set-up, I would like to exclude all cases which lead to a death bifurcation. If these are extremely rare, then I can do so sensibly. I am, however, not so sure that this is true (it is very easy to construct degenerate critical points which die through perturbation, simply by choosing odd-degree polynomials). I am also uncertain whether we can have birth without death, or if both come hand in hand?

---

Finally, this is a bit unrelated from questions **1)** and **2)**, but still related to the overarching question:

**3)** Say we have already ruled out deaths. So our degenerate critical point can either bifurcate into *multiple* critical points (birth scenario), or it will not split, and small perturbations of $f$ will still have only one critical point. Is there a formal way/criterion to distinguish between these two cases?

Comment: (i) How do you define a perturbation? (ii) There should be only one question in one post.

Comment: i) To me, a perturbation of the function $f$ is any function that is close enough to $f$ (in whichever topology I decide to work with). I do not enforce any additional restrictions, though I don't mind them either, if they are required to make (some) of the statements I made true.

Comment: ii) The only real question in the post is at the very beginning. The rest are parts of my own attempt at solving the problem. But if you prefer, @IosifPinelis, feel free to ignore all the later questions and only look at the first one; since that's the one I care about.

Comment: "To me, a perturbation of the function $f$ is any function that is close enough to $f$
 (in whichever topology I decide to work with). Can a perturbation be non-differentiable (say)? I still think it needs to be defined formally.

Comment: You're right, I should have specified this. In my question, $f$ is only assumed to be $\mathcal{C}^2$ (as is necessary to talk about degenerate critical points). Hence, as far as I'm concerned, a perturbation of $f$ is any other, close enough, $\mathcal{C}^2$ function. But once again, I am not opposed to imposing more conditions on what it means to be a "perturbation", if it helps me approach the problem.

Comment: Hi, i think you will find that if you have a birth situation, you willhave a death situation as well (for a different perturbation). The third situation is rare, but there are various ways to detect it. For example if there is a poibt close the critical point where the value is positive, and anothere where it is negative. In general the study of these types of singularities is called catastrophy theory. You can look at the book of golubitsky and guillemin for the whole theory. Other keywords to start your search are cerf theory, morse theory, normal form theory